# group inverse of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be semipositive stable, i.e., real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ are nonnegative. Let $L_{A}: S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ be a linear transformation defined by $L_{A}(X)=AX+XA^T$. I want to construct an example such that $A$ is semipositive stable but group inverse of $L_{A}$ does not exit, i.e., $L_{A}$ is not group invertible.

Note: Group inverse of a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  if exists is the unique matrix $X$ such that $AXA=A$, $XAX=X$ and $AX=XA$. Group inverse of $B$ is denoted by $B^{\#}$.

Example: Here I give one example where $A$ is semipositive stable and $L_{A}^{\#}$ (group inverse of $L_{A}$) exists.
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}$. Set $X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12}\\
x_{12} & x_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $L_{A}(X)=\begin{pmatrix}
2(x_{11}+x_{12}) & x_{12}\\
x_{12} & x_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $L_{A}^{\#}(X)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(x_{11}+x_{12}) & x_{12}\\
x_{12} & x_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$ (one can verify all the three conditions of group inverse for $L_{A}$).

Answer (score 1):

Try $A = 0$.

For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, $L_A$ is non-invertible if $A$ is non-invertible or $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$.

EDIT:  OK, try $$A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$

BTW, where does this "group inverse" concept come from?  It's a strange name, as it doesn't seem to have to do with groups.

Comment: $L_{A}$ may not be invertible but group inverse of $L_{A}$ can exists.

Comment: I got the example sir. The nomenclature group inverse arises from the fact that the positive powers of $A$ and $A^{\#}$ together with the projector $AA^{\#}$ as the identity element, form an abelian group under matrix multiplication, and was named by I. Erdelyi.